# Multiplying values for each generated element

Tags: jquery

I have a form that creates a div for price and total, and an input for the user to select the quantity. I am trying to select the elements by name[], and do the multiplication for each line. I am having an issue with the for loop to run the multiplication on each line.

```js
var getLenthArray = $('div[name="total[]"]').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();

var len = getLenthArray.length;

for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
  $('div[name="cost[]"], input[name="quantity[]"]').keyup(function() {
      $('div[name="total[]"]').text($('input[name="quantity[]"]').val() *
        $('div[name="cost[]"]').text));
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div name="cost[]" id="1">5</div></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" id="1"></td>
    <td><div name="total[]" id="1">Total 1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div name="cost[]" id="2">5</div></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" id="2"></td>
    <td><div name="total[]" id="2">Total 1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div name="cost[]" id="3">5</div></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" id="3"></td>
    <td><div name="total[]" id="3">Total 1</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you're repeating the same `id` in several elements of your code. This is invalid as they must be unique. To fix this you could use a class to group the elements.

From there you can use an `input` event handler on all the `input` elements to calculate the total when they are changed. Lastly, you don't need to give each item a unique name as you can traverse the DOM from the `input` that raised the event to the parent `tr`. You can then use `find()` to gather the required elements and values. Try this:

```js
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var cost = parseFloat($tr.find('.cost').text()) || 0;
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  $tr.find('.total').text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div name="cost[]" class="cost">5</div></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="0"></td>
    <td><div name="total[]" class="total">Total: <span>0</span></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div name="cost[]" class="cost">5</div></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="0"></td>
    <td><div name="total[]" class="total">Total: <span>0</span></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div name="cost[]" class="cost">5</div></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="0"></td>
    <td><div name="total[]" class="total">Total: <span>0</span></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Much better than my approach

Comment: If I am using bootstrap to load this table structure instead of <table>, would I be able to use .prev('div') instead of .closest('tr') ?

Comment: I don't see how that would work as `prev()` is for getting siblings not parents